# IO error in Uploadify in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using uploadify tool to upload my files

When I run the project on my system I dont have error, but when i put it in Host  the error occurs.

i have this Error
IO Error - images.jpg - 100%

I've been using for Send site to Host  software FileZilla

It should be noted. I have exactly this same code  in other websites but It do not have any error

this is my code

```
    var FolderPath = "/Content/Images/News";
    var PageName = "News";
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': '/Content/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Select Image',
            'script': '/Management/Default/Upload',
            'folder': FolderPath,
            'scriptData': { 'PageName': PageName },
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'auto': true,
            'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                alert('Upload Photos A Success ');
                var htmlBox = "<img width='120px' height='120px' id='tImage' src= '" + FolderPath + "/" + fileObj.name + "' />";
                $("#BoxImage").html(htmlBox);
                $("#ImageUrl1").text(fileObj.name);
            }
        });
    });
```

I thought maybe all the required files did not sent to host
But I did not find anything

What is required files for run this cod ??

Comment: Have you set write folder permissions on `"/Content/Images/News"`?

Comment: Thank you 
With your help the problem was solved